# How can I console.log expression in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

As a new "Angularian", I have this:

```
<div data-ng-app="" data-ng-init="">
    <input type="text" ng-model="hello">
    <p>{{hello}}</p>
</div>
```

But I wonder, how can I console.log whatever I type in the expression (ng-model)?

(e.g. if I type "Soylent Green is people" in the text field I want to see it in Chrome's Inspector window)

Comment: have `ng-change` event with function on `input` field & then have that function inside controller & from that function do `console.log($scope.hello)`

Comment: ok, sounds a bit unnecessarily complicated by the angular crew but I'll give it a try nonetheless :)

Comment: may I know what you felt complicated? you have to write code to behave the way you want.

Comment: Just to add my 2 cents. Angular comes with it's own log function, $log. But as @PankajParkar points out, console.log is itself a function, so you have to at least bind it to some event for it to fire and return something. Just for fun I made this jsfiddle, I have no idea how well it will work across other browsers, but it seems to fire nicely in Chrome, but I am not recommending this as a solution. https://jsfiddle.net/lharby/5vr1aoew/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `console.log($scope.hello);` inside your controller.

I suggest you to take a look about Addons/Extensions like Batarang and 
ng-inspector. 
This is the newest one, and as the name suggests, it allows you to inspect your application's scopes.

Answer (score 1):

Use **ng-change** directive with your input tag like

```
<input type="text" ng-model="hello" ng-change="textChange()" >
```

and in your controller

```
$scope.textChange = function () {
          console.log($scope.hello);
  }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/walioulislam/wpjwavrc/

Answer (score 0):

You have a controller for this app, if you don't know about controllers you can read the documentation in [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_controllers.asp)
You can do `console.log($scope.hello)` inside your controller
By default each and every variable you define in HTML is inside $scope object